# List of logins appearing in Edge

Tags: javascript, html, browser, microsoft-edge

I have an web app which is built using javascript and html. When viewing it in the edge browser, if I click on the left of the app next to a table I sometimes get up a grey list on the left of the screen with logins which I have used for logging into the app. This is nothing I have specifically coded and I have not seen this when testing on Firefox or Chrome. What might be causing this? Is it an edge "feature" and how do I stop it from appearing? If I click one of the logins on this list, the list disappears but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know without seeing the app, but sounds like the browsers autocomplete feature. This happens automatically without any coding but you can prevent it.

on the login form where you enter your login details, put in autocomplete="off" so your form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/form" autocomplete="off">
```

this will turn off any previous login information appearing.

Comment: There are no form inputs on that specific page. I am using react so I'm wondering if the dom is corrupted some how and that the login form is still "alive" even though I am not rendering it.